# Appium - PageFactory initElements is not working

Tags: appium, appium-android

I have this Class as my page object:

```
public class LaunchPageObject  {

private AppiumDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

public LaunchPageObject() {

}

public LaunchPageObject(AppiumDriver<AndroidElement> driver) {

    this.driver=driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(this.driver), this);
}

public void Click_SigninNow() {

    lnk_SigninNow.click();
}

@AndroidFindBy(xpath="//android.widget.Button[@text='LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK']")
MobileElement btn_SignupWithEmail;

@AndroidFindBy(xpath="//android.widget.Button[@text='SIGN UP WITH EMAIL']")
MobileElement btn_LoginWithFacebook;

@AndroidFindBy(xpath="//android.widget.TextView[@text='Sign in now']")
MobileElement lnk_SigninNow;
}
```

and I have this class as my test case class:

```
public class LaunchPageTest extends Android {

  @Test
  public void Click_SigninNow() throws MalformedURLException {

  LaunchPageObject lp = new LaunchPageObject(setDriver());
  lp.Click_SigninNow();
  }
}
```

I have this error log:

> FAILED: Click_SigninNow
>       java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.utils.ProxyFactory.getEnhancedProxy(ProxyFactory.java:52)
>       at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.utils.ProxyFactory.getEnhancedProxy(ProxyFactory.java:33)
>       at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.proxyForAnElement(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:217)
>       at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.access$0(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:215)
>       at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator$1.proxyForLocator(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:107)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultFieldDecorator.decorate(DefaultFieldDecorator.java:62)
>       at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.decorate(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:155)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:113)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:105)
>       at POM.LaunchPageObject.(LaunchPageObject.java:35)
>       at TestCases.LaunchPageTest.Click_SigninNow(LaunchPageTest.java:17)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

The test opens the app but is not able to click the element. Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: Can you add setDriver() method too?

Comment: I think setting your AppiumDriver as static will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your page object and test classes like below

```
public class LaunchPageObject {

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath="//android.widget.Button[@text='LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK']")
    MobileElement btn_SignupWithEmail;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath="//android.widget.Button[@text='SIGN UP WITH EMAIL']")
    MobileElement btn_LoginWithFacebook;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath="//android.widget.TextView[@text='Sign in now']")
    MobileElement lnk_SigninNow;

    public void click_SigninNow() {
        lnk_SigninNow.click();
    }

}




public class LaunchPageTest extends Android {

  LaunchPageObject lp       = PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), LaunchPageObject.class);

  @Test
  public void Click_SigninNow() throws MalformedURLException {
    lp.Click_SigninNow();
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this worked for this poster?  The only real difference I can see is that you are not doing a more standard (in my opinion) passing of the driver object as a parameter to the page object and initializing the page object elements inside the page object itself.  Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks Bill for your comments.. I used to follow the different kind of options.  
 Whenever i used to create the page object and will create the respective action method. 
 (Example : if you create object for button and will create the respective action click in the same class )    
 
When coming to the driver creation will create all kind of driver as static method and used to keep the driver into ThreadLoacl .. 
 It will be more helpful for parallel execution..